# Adding the sender address in Redemption

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption and the RDO Objects. I want to be able to set the sender address so that outlook will show who the email is coming from. So I connect to Outlook and the inbox and create my msg object

```
        app = new Application();

        session = app.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession");

        try
        {
            session.Logon(Program.outlookProfileName);
            RDOFolder inbox = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            msg = inbox.Items.Add();
        }
```

I display an email form with the from address(prepopulated based on user), the TO, subject, and body

The user fills in the to box with the intended recipient(s), the subject and the body. They click the Send button. I do the following code

```
        msg.Recipients.ResolveAll();

        msg.SentOnBehalfOfEmailAddress = SenderTB.Text;
        msg.Subject = SubjectTB.Text;
        msg.Body = BodyTB.Text;

        msg.Send();
```

But the sender address does not show properly in outlook. I want the sender address to show whatever was in the SenderTB.Text. How do I set the Sender for the msg object?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a delegate Exchange mailbox? Either set the `SentOnBehalfOfName` (not `SentOnBehalfOfEmailAddress`) or `SentOnBehalfOf` (`RDOAddressEntry`).

Comment: I know that i can get a an AddressEntry based on a name. is it possible to do the reverse? Get an addressEntry based on an email address?

Comment: Sure, RDOAddressBook.ResolveName should work fine if you provide an email address.